# OSX: API for retrieving path to user's ~/temp folder

Tags: macos, path, directory, temp

Does OS X have a separate temp folder for each user?

If so, how to retrieve the temp folder path for the current user programmatically?

PS  Looking at my own OS X file system, I can't see such a folder.

Answer (score 6):

Assuming you are using Objective-C and Foundation: `NSTemporaryDirectory()` should return an `NSString` with the users temporary directory. On my machine that directory is under `/var/folders/`.

For example:

```
NSString *tempDirectory = NSTemporaryDirectory();
```

The documentation says that `NSTemporaryDirectory()` returns "the path of the temporary directory for the current user. If no such directory is currently available, returns nil."

Answer (score 2):

OS X does not (or did not, through early Lion releases; 10.7.3 seems to do so) set `TMPDIR` for use by Unix-like scripts or programs, but many GUI programs make use of a per-user temporary directory under `/var/folders` which you can retrieve using some AppleScript (`temporary items folder` in Scripting Additions) or via `NSTemporaryDirectory()` as noted elsewhere.

Comment: What do you mean? `TMPDIR` is certainly set on my systems. It's the same directory as returned by `NSTemporaryDirectory()`.

Comment: Interesting; I just checked and it does seem to be set.  This must be recent, though, as I have had scripts that set it to point to my external drive if it was attached (and now I know why those haven't been firing when they used to).

Comment: `TMPDIR` is set on a Snow Leopard (10.6.8) machine I've just checked.

Comment: Just a thought: Is it possible that `TMPDIR` is only set in interactive shells.

Comment: TBH I did not check on SL; I only started caring on my MacBook Air which came with Lion.  I wonder then if that was a Lion regression.  I also did not specifically check *after* 10.7.1, only on 10.7.[01].

Comment: @mttrb, it's set for the GUI console session by launchd. Check `launchctl export`. It's present in the environment of GUI apps, too, not just shells.