# Python: module for creating PID-based lockfile?

Tags: python, pid, lockfile

I'm writing a Python script that may or may not (depending on a bunch of things) run for a long time, and I'd like to make sure that multiple instances (started via cron) don't step on each others toes. The logical way to do this seems to be a PID-based lockfile… But I don't want to re-invent the wheel if there is already code to do this.

So, is there a Python module out there which will manage the details of a PID-based lockfile?

Comment: My answer here might also be of interest: [It uses sockets to create a lock file that goes away even if the process is sent a sigkill -][1] 


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/788411/check-to-see-if-python-script-is-running/7758075#7758075

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you can use GPLv2, Mercurial has a module for that:

http://bitbucket.org/mirror/mercurial/src/tip/mercurial/lock.py

Example usage:

```
from mercurial import error, lock

try:
    l = lock.lock("/path/to/lock", timeout=600) # wait at most 10 minutes
    # do something
except error.LockHeld:
     # couldn't take the lock
else:
    l.release()
```

Comment: Thanks for all the other helpful answers, but this turned out to be the simplest solution, as the added mercurial dependency isn't an issue for me (I'm just using it for "little" utility scripts).

Comment: Note that this answer does not work with newer versions of the mercurial library (3.0.1 at the time of writing); the `lock` class expects both `vfs` and `file` args on init (`timeout` is optional).

Comment: `vfs` argument can be generated as following: `from mercurial import scmutil; vfs = scmutil.vfs("/")`. However, relying on an internal module of a larger product probably isn't such a good idea.

Comment: I am getting following error for the lock function : `TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'fname'`. I also wants a variable called `vfs`

Answer (score 13):

This might be of help to you:  [lockfile](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/zc.lockfile)

Answer (score 7):

i've been pretty unhappy with all of those, so i wrote this:

```
class Pidfile():
    def __init__(self, path, log=sys.stdout.write, warn=sys.stderr.write):
        self.pidfile = path
        self.log = log
        self.warn = warn

    def __enter__(self):
        try:
            self.pidfd = os.open(self.pidfile, os.O_CREAT|os.O_WRONLY|os.O_EXCL)
            self.log('locked pidfile %s' % self.pidfile)
        except OSError as e:
            if e.errno == errno.EEXIST:
                pid = self._check()
                if pid:
                    self.pidfd = None
                    raise ProcessRunningException('process already running in %s as pid %s' % (self.pidfile, pid));
                else:
                    os.remove(self.pidfile)
                    self.warn('removed staled lockfile %s' % (self.pidfile))
                    self.pidfd = os.open(self.pidfile, os.O_CREAT|os.O_WRONLY|os.O_EXCL)
            else:
                raise

        os.write(self.pidfd, str(os.getpid()))
        os.close(self.pidfd)
        return self

    def __exit__(self, t, e, tb):
        # return false to raise, true to pass
        if t is None:
            # normal condition, no exception
            self._remove()
            return True
        elif t is PidfileProcessRunningException:
            # do not remove the other process lockfile
            return False
        else:
            # other exception
            if self.pidfd:
                # this was our lockfile, removing
                self._remove()
            return False

    def _remove(self):
        self.log('removed pidfile %s' % self.pidfile)
        os.remove(self.pidfile)

    def _check(self):
        """check if a process is still running

the process id is expected to be in pidfile, which should exist.

if it is still running, returns the pid, if not, return False."""
        with open(self.pidfile, 'r') as f:
            try:
                pidstr = f.read()
                pid = int(pidstr)
            except ValueError:
                # not an integer
                self.log("not an integer: %s" % pidstr)
                return False
            try:
                os.kill(pid, 0)
            except OSError:
                self.log("can't deliver signal to %s" % pid)
                return False
            else:
                return pid

class ProcessRunningException(BaseException):
    pass
```

to be used something like this:

```
try:
    with Pidfile(args.pidfile):
        process(args)
except ProcessRunningException:
    print "the pid file is in use, oops."
```

Answer (score 5):

I know this is an old thread, but I also created a simple lock which only relies on python native libraries:

```
import fcntl
import errno


class FileLock:
    def __init__(self, filename=None):
        self.filename = os.path.expanduser('~') + '/LOCK_FILE' if filename is None else filename
        self.lock_file = open(self.filename, 'w+')

    def unlock(self):
        fcntl.flock(self.lock_file, fcntl.LOCK_UN)

    def lock(self, maximum_wait=300):
        waited = 0
        while True:
            try:
                fcntl.flock(self.lock_file, fcntl.LOCK_EX | fcntl.LOCK_NB)
                return True
            except IOError as e:
                if e.errno != errno.EAGAIN:
                    raise e
                else:
                    time.sleep(1)
                    waited += 1
                    if waited >= maximum_wait:
                        return False
```

Comment: Hi im very new to python and got a project thrown at me where all the dependancies were wrong since it has not been maintained for two years. Having a lock file would have prevented this. My question where exactly do i need to put this file?

Answer (score 4):

I believe you will find the necessary information [here](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-daemon/).  The page in question refers to a package for building daemons in python: this process involves creating a PID lockfile.

Comment: This module seems to be a wrapper on top of the Python standard library lockfile module, which looks like it's atomic to me.

Comment: It is scatter-patched over the github with this https://github.com/khertan/Khweeteur/blob/master/khweeteur/pydaemon/pidlockfile.py being a more recent code by Ben Finney.

Answer (score 2):

There is a [recipe on ActiveState on creating lockfiles](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/498171/).

To generate the filename you can use [os.getpid()](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.getpid) to get the PID.

Comment: The ActiveState solution doesn't look atomic to me.  I think it needs to create the lock-file with a temporary name, like "lockfile.$PID", write the PID into it, then rename "lockfile.$PID" to "lockfile".  Then check by re-reading the lockfile to see if it has your PID.  This is probably overkill for many purposes, but it is the most robust way.

Answer (score 2):

You can try **PID**: https://pypi.org/project/pid/

As the documentation shows, you can lock a function simply adding the decorator `@pidfile()` on the top of function/method name.

```
from pid.decorator import pidfile


@pidfile()
def main():
  pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
  main()
```

The default location for pidfile self check (the file who says if you can execute the code or not) is '/var/run'. You can change it as follows:

```
@pidfile(piddir='/path/to/a/custom/location')
```

For other params, see: https://github.com/trbs/pid/blob/95499b30e8ec4a473c0e6b407c03ce644f61c643/pid/base.py#L41

Unfortunatly, this lib's documentation is a little bit poor.