# Checking running python script within the python script

Tags: python, linux, unix

I am running a python script that may or may not take few hours to complete.

In the beginning of my python script, I want to check if this python script is already running or not.

If it is already running, I want to exit my current python that I just started.

For example:

python started 1AM and keeps on running until 3AM
started another one at 2AM without knowing it is already running. 
I want my 2AM python to check and exit since it is already running.

How can I write this python?

---

This is what I tried for locking..

```
try:
    l = lock.lock("/home/auto.py", timeout=600) # wait at most 10 minutes

except error.LockHeld:
    e = sys.exc_info()[0]
    logging.error("Error: " + str(e) + " at main gatering Stats")
    smtpObj.sendmail(sender, receivers, message + "Error: " + str(e) + " at main gatering stats")
    exit("Fail: " + str(e) + " at main gathering Stats")
else:
    l.release()
```

so I thought this will wait for 10 minutes if it is still running then exit.. if it is not running anymore, then run the current python

Comment: how is this different to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29354841/how-can-i-stop-my-python-script-when-another-python-script-is-running?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I tried most of the answers but its either not working or I can't get it to work

Comment: So a lockfile did not work?

Comment: I tried lockfile as will since it was most voted.. I am not sure if it was my coding that didnt work or not.. I couldn't get it to work

Comment: You should create a temp lock file for that. Check for the lock file then exit or whatever.

Comment: @Tim post your code here

Comment: @Tim, a correctly created lockfile would work as would the answer I deleted. you should add what you tried and how it did not work.

Comment: @SarenArterius I edited my question with the code I tried

Comment: @PadraicCunningham please take a look at my edited question

Comment: I presume lock refers to `mercurial/lock.py`?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham `mercurial/lock.py`? `home/auto.py` is my python path

Comment: @SarenArterius Do you have any idea what I need to do?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Do you have any idea what I need to do?

Comment: @Tim, what is `lock.lock`?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1444790/python-module-for-creating-pid-based-lockfile I just used this since previous answer was pointing at this link

Comment: so you installed mercurial?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham oh that's what you meant.. yes I did

Comment: Do you want the file to run when the running file exits or to end the current script completely?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham if python is running already.. I want to kill the new python totally

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using the [lockfile-create](http://linux.die.net/man/1/lockfile-create) command with the `r` flag to retry a specified amount of times catching a `CalledProcessError` and exiting, the `-p` flag will store the `pid` of the process :

```
import os
import sys
from time import sleep

from subprocess import check_call, CalledProcessError

try:
    check_call(["lockfile-create", "-q","-p", "-r", "0", "-l", "my.lock"])
except CalledProcessError as e:
    print("{} is already running".format(sys.argv[0]))
    print(e.returncode)
    exit(1)


# main body

for i in range(10):
    sleep(2)
    print(1)

check_call(["rm","-f","my.lock"])
```

Running a `test.py` script with the code above while one is already running outputs the following:

```
$ python  lock.py 
lock.py is already running
4
```

**Options**

**-q, --quiet**

> Suppress any output. Success or failure will only be indicated by the exit status.

**-v, --verbose**

> Enable diagnostic output.

**-l, --lock-name**

> Do not append .lock to the filename. This option applies to lockfile-create, lockfile-remove, lockfile-touch, or lockfile-check.

**-p, --use-pid**

> Write the current process id (PID) to the lockfile whenever a lockfile is created, and use that pid when checking a lock's validity. See the lockfile_create(3) manpage for more information. This option applies to lockfile-create, lockfile-remove, lockfile-touch, and lockfile-check.

**-o, --oneshot**

> Touch the lock and exit immediately. This option applies to lockfile-touch and mail-touchlock. When not provided, these commands will run forever, touching the lock once every minute until killed.

**-r retry-count, --retry retry-count**

> Try to lock filename retry-count times before giving up. Each attempt will be delayed a bit longer than the last (in 5 second increments) until reaching a maximum delay of one minute between retries. If retry-count is unspecified, the default is 9 which will give up after 180 seconds (3 minutes) if all 9 lock attempts fail.

**Description**

> The lockfile_create function creates a lockfile in an NFS safe way.
>
> If flags is set to L_PID then lockfile_create will not only check for an existing lockfile, but it will read the contents as well to see if it contains a process id in ASCII. If so, the lockfile is only valid if that process still exists.
>
> If the lockfile is on a shared filesystem, it might have been created by a process on a remote host. Thus the process-id checking is useless and the L_PID flag should not be set. In this case, there is no good way to see if a lockfile is stale. Therefore if the lockfile is older then 5 minutes, it will be removed. That is why the lockfile_touch function is provided: while holding the lock, it needs to be refreshed regularly (every minute or so) by calling lockfile_touch ().
>
> The lockfile_check function checks if a valid lockfile is already present without trying to create a new lockfile.
>
> Finally the lockfile_remove function removes the lockfile.

The [Algorithm](http://linux.die.net/man/3/lockfile_create)

The algorithm that is used to create a lockfile in an atomic way, even over NFS, is as follows:

1

> A unique file is created. In printf format, the name of the file is .lk%05d%x%s. The first argument (%05d) is the current process id. The second argument (%x) consists of the 4 minor bits of the value returned by time(2). The last argument is the system hostname.

2

> Then the lockfile is created using link(2). The return value of link is ignored.

3

> Now the lockfile is stat()ed. If the stat fails, we go to step 6.

4

> The stat value of the lockfile is compared with that of the temporary file. If they are the same, we have the lock. The temporary file is deleted and a value of 0 (success) is returned to the caller.

5

> A check is made to see if the existing lockfile is a valid one. If it isn't valid, the stale lockfile is deleted.

6

> Before retrying, we sleep for n seconds. n is initially 5 seconds, but after every retry 5 extra seconds is added up to a maximum of 60 seconds (an incremental backoff). Then we go to step 2 up to retries times.

There seems to be an equivalent package  called [lockfile-progs](http://rpm.pbone.net/index.php3/stat/4/idpl/15273807/dir/redhat_el_5/com/lockfile-progs-0.1.15-2.el5.x86_64.rpm.html) on **redhat**.

On mac you could use [lockfile](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/lockfile.1.html) and do something like:

```
import os
import sys
from time import sleep
import os
from subprocess import Popen, CalledProcessError, check_call


p = Popen(["lockfile", "-r", "0", "my.lock"])
p.wait()
if p.returncode == 0:
    with open("my.pid", "w") as f:
        f.write(str(os.getpid()))
else:
    try:
        with open("my.pid") as f:
            # see if process is still running or lockfile
            # is left over from previous run.
            r = f.read()
            check_call(["kill", "-0", "{}".format(r)])
    except CalledProcessError:
        # remove old lock file and create new
        check_call(["rm", "-f", "my.lock"])
        check_call(["lockfile", "-r", "0", "my.lock"])
        # update pid
        with open("my.pid", "w") as out:
            out.write(str(os.getpid()))
        print("Deleted stale lockfile.")
    else:
        print("{} is already running".format(sys.argv[0]))
        print(p.returncode)
        exit(1)
# main body

for i in range(10):
    sleep(1)
    print(1)
check_call(["rm", "-f", "my.lock"])
```

In your case maybe using a socket would work:

```
from socket import socket, gethostname, error, SO_REUSEADDR, SOL_SOCKET
from sys import argv
import  errno



sock = socket()

# Create a socket object
host = gethostname()  
# /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_local_port_range is  32768  61000 on my Ubuntu Machine
port = 60001  
# allow connection in TIME_WAIT
sock.setsockopt(SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, 1)

try:
    sock.bind((host, port))
    sock.connect((host, port))
except error as e:
    # [Errno 99] Cannot assign requested address
    if e.errno == errno.EADDRNOTAVAIL:
        print("{} is already running".format(argv[0]))
        exit(1)
    # else raise the error
    else:
        raise e

# main body
from time import sleep

while True:
    print(1)
    sleep(2)

sock.close()
```

Comment: so this will run for the first python and on the scond python it will exit out? also at `heck_call(["lockfile-create","-r",  "3", "--lock-name","my.lock"])` what is `--lock-name` and `my.lock`? is this just any name I can create?

Comment: @Tim, the name can be anything,  it is created when the script is run. Try it with the example I provided

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./automate.py", line 430, in <module>
    check_call(["lockfile-create","-r",  "3", "--lock-name","my.lock"])
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 537, in check_call
    retcode = call(*popenargs, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 524, in call
    return Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs).wait()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 711, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1308, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception`

Comment: Can you run `lockfile-create` from bash?

Comment: you mean just `lockfile-create` ? no `-bash: lockfile-create: command not found`

Comment: what are you running this on?

Comment: I am practicing it on my macbook which is unix.. but the school server is linux ubuntu

Comment: I don't use mac so cannot comment on that but I am using Ubuntu and it works as expected. What are you  going to be running it on?

Comment: do you have lockfile installed on mac?

Comment: I realized I don't have it installed and by using ssh to the school server, it wont let me install it either.. so I guess I have to look for other way of doing it

Comment: You don't have to install it on ubuntu, it should already be there. You can install lockfile on mac as in the second part of the answer

Comment: `sudo apt-get install procmail` wont do it either same as yum.. just realized our school sever dont have lockfile function and cant install it

Comment: I don't get what you mean by won't do it either? What happens?

Comment: can't install procmail to the school server.. and it is not already installed

Comment: I thought the school used an Ubuntu server?

Comment: i think they are.. but it is not installed in there

Comment: Linux version 3.10.0-123.20.1.el7.x86_64

Comment: does `cat /etc/redhat-release` output anything?

Comment: Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.0 (Maipo)

Comment: then you are using redhat not ubuntu. There are a few issues in the script like if it crashes the lock file won't be deleted so I will iron those out later or tomorrow.  for now install http://man.flashnux.com/en/redhat/9/9.0/man1/lockfile.1.html