# Reading data from excel by using python

Tags: python, pandas

By using pandas, am reading particularly few cell values from a excel sheet in a periodic interval. The cell values are update in 2mins but the problem is when my program read values after 2mins, its always getting old value not updated one. How to solve it ?

using standard python pandas library.

```
def animate(i):
        df = pd.read_excel(r"example.xlsm",'Analysis').iloc[12:13,10:18].dropna(axis='columns')
        print(df)
ani=animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate,interval=30000)
plt.show()
```

df value should be return as excel sheet value updated but its not happening.
There is no two threads in python reading simeltanously, call values are updated by excel refresh mechanism not by python.

Comment: your function isn't returning anything (it's only `print`ing `df`).

Comment: You are restricting the `df` always to the same few items by means of the `.iloc`. So even if the new data are read in by `read_excel()`, you instantly throw them away.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Streaming data for pandas df](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32594137/streaming-data-for-pandas-df)

Comment: 1. If df is same value then whats the point return, in fact all my other logic is written in animate(i) function.

Comment: 2.yes , I am interested in particular cell value of excel sheet that's why use .iloc and those cell values are updating in 2mins.

Comment: don't understand  Possible duplicate of Streaming data for pandas df