# How to restart a python script using another?

Tags: python, cron, scheduled-tasks, startup

('The First script' takes input from the user and 'the second script' notify the task.)

I have been trying to restart a python script using another one but i couldn't succeed it after trying to do a few methods. I developed a reminder, notify user when time previously set by the user has arrived, app works on Linux and it have 2 python script. First one is for taking input that given by the user to schedule a task. For example, "Call the boss at 12:30 pm". Then Linux is going to notify it at 12:30 pm. The other one is checking the inputs and notify them when the time comes.

In first script, i am trying to restart the other script when the user give a new task because the script needs to read the new task to notify it. Also I want to terminate the first script when it ran the second script. But the second script must still be working. In first script, I tried these commands to do that:

```
os.system(f"pkill -f {path2}")
os.system(f"python {path2}")
```

These aren't work.

Also I want to run the second script at the startup of my os.

Summary:

1- I wanna restart a python script using another one and the first one should be terminated when the second one is run.

2- I wanna run the second script at the startup of my os.

Repository about my reminder app is [here](https://github.com/sifirib/reminder).

Comment: You answer is available in this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3054740/terminate-a-python-script-from-another-python-script

Comment: to start at startup you could use `@reboot` in `cron`. But all this looks similar to program called `daemon` or `service` which has command `start`, `stop`, `restart` and they are automatically started after reboot. Maybe you should search information for this type of programs.

Comment: I tried to use cron but it gave me this "python3: can't open file 'reminder2.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory" when os is start.

Comment: The command that i added in crontab is "@reboot sh /home/hrx/launcher_for_reminder.sh > /home/hrx/logsforreminder/cronlog 2>&1"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**About 1 :**

Assuming the name of the other script is 2.py (Changeable with the code below), this worked for me pretty well:

`1.py:`

```
import subprocess
import os
import time

OTHER_SCRIPT_NAME = "2.py"

process_outputs = subprocess.getoutput("ps aux | grep " + OTHER_SCRIPT_NAME) # Searching for the process running 2.py
wanted_process_info = process_outputs.split("\n")[0] # Getting the first line only
splitted_process_info = wanted_process_info.split(" ") # Splitting the string
splitted_process_info = [x for x in splitted_process_info if x != ''] # Removing empty items
pid = splitted_process_info[1] # PID is the secend item in the ps output
os.system("kill -9 " + str (pid)) # Killing the other process
exit()

time.sleep(1000) # Will not be called because exit() was called before
```

`2.py:`

```
import time

time.sleep(100)
```

**About 2:**

In linux, you can execute scripts on startup by writing it into the `/etc/rc.local` file

Just run your scripts from the rc.local file and you are good to go:

`/etc/rc.local:`

```
python '/path/to/your/scripts'
```

Comment: Why should i add "time.sleep(100)" to the 2.py and where should i place it?
One more, if time.sleep(1000) will not be called, why do we add it?

Comment: There isnt any file called rc.local in etc.

Comment: I just created rc.local file under etc, made it executable, add the command  with path of my app above the line exit 0 and restart the os but it didn't work. I'm sure. @Dharman

Comment: All of the time.sleeps were to show that this method works.
About /etc/rc.local - what was the command you were trying to run?
I would advise you to just 'mkdir /home/[your_username]/tmp1' to test if the script really runs or not (after reset you should have tmp1 directory under your user's home directory).
Should work.
Also - Which distro of linux you are working with?

Comment: There wasn't rc.local file under /etc and i created it and add these commands in it:
(Then i made it executable)

`
#!/bin/sh -e
#
# rc.local
#
# This script is executed at the end of each multiuser runlevel.
# Make sure that the script will "exit 0" on success or any other
# value on error.
#
# In order to enable or disable this script just change the execution
# bits.
#
# By default this script does nothing.

exit 0

python '/home/hrx/Desktop/reminder/reminder.py'
`


Its Linux Mint 20

Comment: Wow its my bad probably i add the command below exit 0 instead of above.

Comment: 1.py that was answered by @davidalk works well but probably there is no way to restart 1.py with pid. I need to restart my script. That's why, I run it as a service on linux, but when i start the service the status command says: [here](justpaste.it/5zbk2).
And paths of both python and python3 are [here](justpaste.it/3n365).