# Restart python script from other script

Tags: python, restart

I already searched several solutions on this site, but unfortunately the provided ones didn't work out for me.

Let's say I have a python script called "DataGen.py" that stops running (green arrow is clickable) because some background program is crashing. Unfortunately, there is no exception being thrown, which is why I need a workaround:

What I'm searching for is another python script called "RestartScript.py" that restarts "DataGen.py" 60 seconds after it has stopped running.

I tried something like:

```
from os import system
from time import sleep

while True:
    system('DataGen.py')
    sleep(300)
```

Comment: Have you tried `os.system("python DataGen.py")`?

Comment: This might help you to identify whether your script is currently running or not: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/788411/check-to-see-if-python-script-is-running

Comment: @AlexYu this seems to work. What does the sleep command do in this context?

Comment: It [suspend execution of the calling thread for the given number of seconds](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/time.html#time.sleep)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `system` function executes what command you use as input.. See [link](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.system). As such, this would be how you would run it to achieve the results you desire:

`system('python DataGen.py')`

Also, whatever value used as input in the `sleep` function is supposed to be seconds..
Using this logic, your code reruns every 300 seconds.

See below for full solution:

```
from os import system
from time import sleep

while True:
    system('python DataGen.py')
    sleep(60)
```

Comment: It's a good start, but if you want to monitor `DataGen.py` from a master process, `subprocess.call` or the likes would probably be a better choice. Besides, there is no `restart if crashed` logic, which I would find much more interesting. I think a satisfying solution would be to pass `DataGen.py`'s pid to a `monitor` function, that would regularly check if the process is still running, and restart it if it crashed. Maybe `os.system('ps')` then a lookup for this pid would be a good starter.

Comment: @Rightleg This would also be better for my purposes. The link "DocDriven" posted under the question is what you're refering to I think.