# Python, Detect if duplicate process is running

Tags: python, process, duplicates

I want to detect if theres a duplicate process is running, for example notepad, if there are more than 1 notepads open, it will detect that and then close all the notepads. Well its not on notepads, its for a program. I just used notepads as an example.

Comment: What is the use case of this?

It really doesn't sound like something you'd want, considering, especially on windows, system processes/services are ran under scvhost name. Killing them could cause a lot of problems.

Comment: Do you want to restrict your own program, or should your program restrict another one? What do you consider duplicates - same process name, same executable, same service?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check to see if python script is running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/788411/check-to-see-if-python-script-is-running)